# Make iFrame content width the iFrame's width

Tags: html, css, iframe

How can I make iFrame content width the iFrame's width? For example, if the iframe is declared as so:

```
<iframe style="width: 300px; height: 600px;" src="http://teamfreehugs.github.io/stackexchange/questionpacker/clean.html?question=4&amp;site=stackoverflow"></iframe>
```

How can I make it so that the iFrame's content will have a smaller webpage, and not show the scrollbars? Also, I don't want to hide the scrollbars, I want to make it unable to show by reducing the inner page's size. Example:

This is what I have:
[image]

Here, the iFrame's inner page thinks the page size is my regular page size, not the iFrame's page size, making the `<hr>` be longer that it should be.

What I want is the scrollbars to disappear and the page inside thinks it has a smaller width. For example, if I set the width to `width: 100px`, the inner page thinks the window is only 100px, meaning the `<hr>` will only display for 100 pixels.

Comment: Why not use `overflow:hidden` on the iframe?

Comment: @AhsN because it only hides the scrollbar. I want the internal page size to also be reduced to the iFrame's width

Answer (score 0):

http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

May be this technique will come quite handy. =)
It's not only for videos but for any embedded content. You can even use it for tricks with background-images and such.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{ 
width: 100%; 
}
```

on your iframe content.

and there are apparently other elements in your content which have bigger width, give them max-width: 100%;

Comment: Sorry, but this wasn't what I wanted. Now the iFrame takes up the whole page. I want the iFrame to keep the size, and it tells the inner page its width for the body, instead of using my screen size